How to decode dictionary of dictionaries with NSSecureCoding
I have an existing iOS app with years of serialization using NSCoding. As NSCoding is deprecated in favor of NSSecureCoding, I'm switching over. Most data has been very straightforward, but I can't figure how to decode dictionaries of dictionaries.
For example, with classic NSCoding:
if let aToBToC = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: aToBToCKey) as? [String: [String: String]] {
    self.aToBToC = aToBToC
}

When I try to write this with NSSecureCoding, I can't figure what to use as the object type:
if let aToBToC = decoder.decodeObject(withKeyClass: NSString.self, objectClass: ?????, forKey: aToBToCKey) as? [String: [String: String]] {
    self.aToBToC = aToBToC
}

Is there perhaps someway to make an AnyClass for [String: String]?
As an analogy, the way this is solved in Java with Jackson deserialization is new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(): i.e. there's a break glass way to define more complicated types than String.class. Does something similar exist for Swift?
I have the constraint that I can't change the serialization format without breaking all existing users.

How about NSDictionary.self? And cast to String when necessary.

Regarding years of serialization consider to move away from oblective-c-ish decoding patterns toward Swift native ones.

Re casting: the whole point of the new NSSecureCoding is that not knowing the precise type and then casting is insecure and disallowed. When I try that, it says "This method only supports decoding non-nested collections. Please remove the following or use '-decodeObjectOfClasses: forKey:'". I can't find any version of that other init that works. E.g. I've tried withKeysOfClasses: [NSString.self], objectsOfClasses: [NSDictionary.self, NSString.self, NSString.self] and many variants. It appears there are no real examples of that call online!

Re moving away from NSCoding in favor of Swift native ones: wow, I thought I was doing the Apple-recommended thing, thank you! My goal here is just to do this in a supported, non-deprecated way, so I'd accept that as an answer! Is Codable/JSONEncoder the current "right" away?

In a pure Swift environment Codable is the best choice if the objects are JSON or Property List compliant.
